# Will bloom filter always return false positives under certain conditions?

Tags: data-structures, language-agnostic, bloom-filter

Assume a bloom filter api, with 2 parameters - 1. number of bits in bloom filter (n) and 2. expected number of insertions (m).

### Question:

Will `m > n` always lead to `complete` false positives? By `complete` I intend to say, will every test for 'contains(element)' method return true, after m > n condition ?

Comment: No. Perhaps you should explain why you think this might the case.

Answer (score 1):

The bloom filter will always answer yes not when your m > n, but when all n of its bits are 1 - then every query of h positions (where h is the number of hash functions) will yield h 1s.  Still, the typical setup that optimizes the space vs. false positive rate tradeoff is when the probability of any bit being set is 1/2.  The analysis is shown on the Bloom filter wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter